# How to connect my react native app to existing database using Amplify?

Tags: react-native, aws-amplify

I have react native app that already at the store.

I decided to move my database and my frontend and backend using Amplify.

I would like to connect my react native app using Amplify too, my needs are to check if user is sign in and get access token, refresh token, token expired date, sign out and using the different apis on the backend to get data...

I was looking on different documents like  [this one](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/tutorials/building-react-native-apps/) but couldn't find a way to connect to exist one, the only option I have seen is to create a new database only for the mobile...

What are my options? I thought maybe I should create login and refreshToken functions in the backend and only call those functions every time I need to log in or refresh a token... or maybe I should use configuration file somewhere? I was thinking about this file `awsExports` but not sure this is the right one, there's no explanation about it

Thanks in advance